# How to test Single Linked List using Assert.assertEquals()

Tags: java, testing, junit, singly-linked-list

i am trying to test singly linked list using Assert.assertEqual(expected, actual) the linked list has a node index and a value. how can i use Assert.assertEquals() to test it.

This is my code

```
@Test
void nonEmptyTest() throws ListAccessError {
    SingleLinkedList<Integer> list = new SingleLinkedList<Integer>();
    SingleLinkedList<Integer> expList = new SingleLinkedList<Integer>();
    list.add(0,10);
    list.add(1,20);
    list.add(2,30);
    expList.add(0,10);
    expList.add(1,20);
    expList.add(2,30);
    Assert.assertEquals(expList, list);
}
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with what you have already done?

Comment: I am getting an error for this. java.lang.AssertionError: expected: linkedList.list.SingleLinkedList<[]> but was: linkedList.list.SingleLinkedList<[]>
Expected :linkedList.list.SingleLinkedList<[]> 
Actual   :linkedList.list.SingleLinkedList<[]>
 <Click to see difference>

Comment: Have you overriden the ```equals(Object)``` method in you SingleLinkedList class to check for equality?

Comment: i dont have that method

Comment: Yes you do.  It's implemented in Object, the base of all classes.  So if you don't implement equals() then you get Object.equals(), but *it doesn't know how to compare your linked lists* so two lists will never be equal.  Consult any Java textbook for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override  `boolean equals(Object obj)` method for you to expect the assert on the actual values of the list.

Here's a sample on how to override

*(Note: I don't know your implementation of SingleLinkedList, you can get an idea from the following code and implement accordingly)*

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    SingleLinkedList<Integer> listToCompare = (SingleLinkedList<Integer>) obj;
    SingleLinkedList<Integer> thisList = this;
    while (listToCompare != null && thisList != null) {
        if (!listToCompare.getData().equals(thisList.getData()))
            return false;

        listToCompare = listToCompare.getNext();
        thisList = thisList.getNext();
    }
    if (listToCompare == null && thisList == null)
        return true;

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two different objects to find out whether they're equal, your class that defines those objects generally needs to implement the equals() method.  Otherwise Java has no way to know what 'equality' is supposed to mean.

That is, your problem is not in the unit test, it's in the class being tested.  The
unit test did its job :-)